# Why the compose canvas draw things only show at preview function but not display on the running screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

#### Descript

I want to draw a line at the compose with the compose canvas inside a compose widget,but it's just show at the preview!
If just copy the canvas part code,it can Correct display！

#### The compose code

```
Card(
        elevation = 6.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = backgroundColor),
        ) {
            AsyncImage(modifier = Modifier
                .height(180.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .padding(12.dp)
             ...  )
              

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .weight(0.7f)
                ) {
                   ...
                }

                Canvas(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(0.3f)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(start = 6.dp)
                ) {
                   // NOT SHOW !!!
                    drawLine(
                        color = Color.White,
                        start = Offset(0f, 0f),
                        end = Offset(0f, size.height),
                        strokeWidth = 2f,
                        pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(20f, 20f), 0f),
                    )
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

#### SceenShot

[image: issue screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an issue related to size of Canvas. Check if it doesn't return width or height zero in your Composable.

In Jetpack Compose Canvas is nothing other than `Spacer` with `Modifier.drawBehind{}`

```
@Composable
fun Canvas(modifier: Modifier, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) =
    Spacer(modifier.drawBehind(onDraw))
```

Which you can use `Modifier.drawWithContent{}` on your own Composable instead using `Box` and `Canvas` Composabble

you can use `Modifier.drawWithContent` for instance such as

```
Column {
    val drawModifier = Modifier
        .drawWithContent {
            drawContent()
            drawLine(
                color = Color.White,
                start = Offset(size.width*.8f, 0f),
                end = Offset(size.width*.8f, size.height),
                strokeWidth = 2f,
                pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(20f, 20f), 0f),
            )
        }
        .width(200.dp)
        .height(100.dp)



    Box(modifier = drawModifier.background(Color.Red)) {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, according to your advice, I checked the canvas height, the height set fill Max height is no use. I guess the reason is the root element `card` is not set a fixed height.

Comment: That's most likely the issue. First thing you should do is to check size.height inside DrawScope and set a Modifier that returns non zero height and width to be able to use size as reference

Comment: But assigning Modifier.drawWithContent should return correct dimensions of a Composable because they get the dimension after they are laid out.